# how to run an echo command for terminal through PHP

Tags: php, shell, email, exec

Been stuck all day trying to mail from a `<form>` through php with a terminal command that is send to my server.

The reason for this is that I was using phpmailer to send mails from the website, but then google flagged my website as illegal login.

So I thought this could be easily done by installing a mail server to my webserver and mail through that.

So far so good, got my mail server setup and mails from command line works great.

But now the hard part: getting the website to pickup the variables from my form and putting them in a command for the terminal.

What I tried several ways to put the command into a variable and execute the variable but nothing worked so far.

What I have now is the following:

PHP part:

```
<?php

//Database
require_once 'includes/dbconfig2.php';

// Get our database connector
require("includes/conn.php");

//Class
$reg=new USER($DBcon);

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
    $email = "mail@to.address";
    $subject = "Hey, ik ben er bij op de trouwerij!";
    $contentmail = '<? echo "echo "<b>Bedankt voor het melden.</b><br><br>Mail van: Willem<br>Mail adres: mail@from.address<br><br><b>Bericht:</b><br><br>test" | mail -s "$(echo -e "Hey, ik ben er bij op de trouwerij.\nContent-Type: text/html")" mail@to.address "?>';
}




if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $errors = array();



if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
    $errors[] = '<p><font color="#FF0000">Naam, email en bericht zijn verplicht!</p>';
} else {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    $errors[] = '<p><font color="#FF0000">Dat is geen geldig email adres</p>';
    }
    if (ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '', $name)) === false) {
        $errors[] = '<p><font color="#FF0000">Naam mag enkel letters bevatten</p>'; 
    }
}
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    (shell_exec('$contentmail'));
 {
     if(true)
     {
    header('Location: sent.php?sent'); 
    exit();//redirect user  
     }
 }

}
}

?>
```

And the form:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="index.php" method="post">
            <div class="row animate-box">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="sr-only">Naam</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Uw naam"<?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) {echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; }?>/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                    </div>                  

                </div>
                </div>  
            <div class="row animate-box">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"<?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) {echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; }?>/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row animate-box">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="message" class="sr-only">Bericht:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Bericht"/><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) {echo strip_tags($_POST['message']) ; }?></textarea>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row animate-box">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1">

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name="send" value="Ja, ik ben er bij!" style="left: auto"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Can somebody please help me out here on why this code isn't being executed on terminal/shell of the server and how I can get this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Made a bash script to take over the command that I have in the variable and letting the exec command execute the bash script. The script itself works on the server from the terminal, but no luck from the page. For some reason my page keeps reloading to index.php instead of executing the script while a php with only the execute and variables does work.

Comment: I would write row to a database table called something like `mail_queue` with all required params to send the correct email to the correct place. Then make your commandline script read that table and create the email. A CRON job in fact

Comment: yeah but that is not what I want to do, I want to learn how to execute commands from terminal instead... I now made a bash script that can do the mailing but still don't get it working that php executes the script so the mail gets sent...

Answer (score 0):

This code: `shell_exec('$contentmail')` is trying to execute the string `$contentmail`, not its contents. This is the difference between [single and double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in PHP.

The second problem is the contents of `$contentmail` variable - the shell would be trying to run `<? echo "echo "<b>Bedankt voo...`, which is not a valid command.

If you have your own server with SMTP server installed, you can try sending e-mails using PHP's built-in function `mail()` or (better) use PHPMailer locally.

Comment: because of that i changed the way I want to do this... I now made a bash script which holds the command instead of a variable, and I want to let php execute the script, but for some reason that isn't executed... The way i have it now is here: http://pasted.co/cfafa372

Comment: PS: I want to learn how to execute it from terminal or let php execute bash scripts instead of using the easy way ;)

Comment: Oké, found the problems. The execute that seemed to be not working was in fact being executed but no mail was send die to www-data not having maildir, and the reload was due to a bad edit I accidentally did while doing some other edits...